# Firebase - Cannot read property 'uid' of null

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I run this code, I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null`. Why does this happen? I have some very similar code above it but that runs fine. Here is the error-throwing code:

```
  function checkForSession(testNo) {
    user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    firebase.database().ref("users/" + user.uid + "/tests/" + testNo).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var datas = snapshot.val();
        hour = datas.lastActiveHour;
        minute = datas.lastActiveMinute;
        day = datas.lastActiveDay;
        month = datas.lastActiveMonth;
        year = datas.lastActiveYear;
        pos = datas.position;
        console.log("Last position: " + pos);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I think, this should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901056/5699040

Comment: I tried putting `userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` in the 'onAuthStateChanged` loop but then I get the error `userID is not defined`

Comment: Why is that not working ?

Comment: You need to declare your variable like so:
`var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`

Comment: I still get the same error. Any ideas on what might be going on?

Comment: use this Line `String user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();`

Comment: Still no luck :-( .