# How check if the email in firebase is verified in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

My skills with firebase is basic, what i want to get is, only the users who have the verified mail will be able to enter the app, if not show the error of the email that has not been verified. here my code:

```
login (){

    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const emailVerified = user.emailVerified;

    const validate = this.refs.formId.getValue();
    if (validate && emailVerified != 'false') {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(validate.email, validate.password)
        .then(() => {

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {

            Toast.show({ text: 'Wrong password!', position: 'bottom', buttonText: 'Try Again' })

            if (emailVerified === 'false') {

            Toast.show({ text: 'Email Not Verified!', position: 'bottom', buttonText: 'Try Again' })

            }else{
            Toast.show({ text: 'Something Wrong!', position: 'bottom', buttonText: 'Try Again' })
            }

        });
    }

}
```

I get this error: **null is not an object (evaluating 'user.emailVerified)**

Comment: Same situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883981/cant-get-currentuser-on-load

Comment: Yes, but how i can integrate the two functions i mean the auth and onchange ?

Answer (score 1):

From notice under the example just like your way to utilize  `firebase.auth().currentUser` in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users):

> Note: currentUser might also be null because the auth object has not
>   finished initializing. If you use an observer to keep track of the
>   user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case.

@bdroid, you don't need to integrate them, by reforming the flow of this login process. I think this also provides a proper login flow, call `signInWithEmailAndPassword` first, after detecting if the user is verified, decide what to do separately on complete authorization login and uncompleted one:

```
login (){

  const validate = this.refs.formId.getValue();
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(validate.email, validate.password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
      Toast.show({ text: 'Wrong password!', position: 'bottom', buttonText: 'Try Again' });
    }

  });

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      if (user.emailVerified === false) {
        Toast.show({ text: 'Email Not Verified!', position: 'bottom', buttonText: 'Try Again' });
      } else {

        // successful login 

      }
    } else {
      //  Toast.show({ text: 'Something Wrong!', position: 'bottom', buttonText: 'No user is signed in.' }); 
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: I test it but i still can login when my the . email is not verified

Comment: i get this error: null is not an object (evaluating 'validate.email)

Comment: @bdroid It's seem the problem is not at the `firebase.auth()` at all, you don't fetch the value in the form properly in very first.

Comment: @bdorid, but I'm wondering how you can login when `validate` is null ? `I test it but i still can login when my the . email is not verified`

Comment: i have the form: <Form
     ref="formId"
     type={this.user}
     options={this.options}
     />

    <Button rounded block onPress={this.login.bind(this)} style={styles.button_auth}> <Text>Enter</Text> </Button>

    <Button block style={styles.text_auth}><Text style={styles.text_auth}>Forgot Password?</Text></Button>

Comment: @bdroid, I've updated the answer that I remove the single quote around `'false'`, if the method return boolean value, it causes problem, but this does not explain why `validate` being `null` yet.

Comment: @bdroid, and make sure you deploy this login function in `componentDidMount()` or after the component is rendered. `ref` could not refer to element which is not mounted yet.

Comment: @bdroid, you need to explain this more clearly, you said the user logged in, but you said there is error message: validate is null