# Data missing after JSON.stringify a firebase object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app linked to firebase. When a user logs in, I assign his object `firebase.auth().currentUser` to a variable. Then, I add a property  (`username`) to that variable . The thing is that when I `console.log(currentUser)` I get the object with the added property. But, when I try to `JSON.stringify` it then `JSON.parse` it again (i do this to store it on `localStorage`)  I can't find my property `username` that I added. What's happening here ?

```js
var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser

currentUser.username = 'Foo';

console.log(currentUser) // => i get my prop username here

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(currentUser))) // => i cant find my added prop here
```

Comment: what's the result of this : `console.log(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))`

Comment: Objects in console are live (not snapshots) and will show modifictions made to them after they are logged. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(currentUser))` will probably see it is empty object and you have a synchronicity issue

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi same object on JSON format obviously

Comment: Please include a minimal repro so we can offer solid advice. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some great tips on asking effective questions and getting superstar answers. Since you're taking an object Firebase manages and modifying it, it may be overwriting your changes. Copy out the data you need to your own object instead. Also, what's the point? Why are you storing ephemeral/changeable data provided by Firebase in localStorage? Hint: it's already stored there. Maybe just store username separately?

Comment: @charlietfl true , and how can i fix that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901056/1175966

Comment: @Kato i want to store it on localStorage because i don't wanna do much async requests in case the user refreshes the page ...and why i dont store the username seperately ? i know i can but i just wanna know why the `JSON.stringify(currentUser)` is mutating my object to its initial value

Comment: Guys if you can't answer please consider giving an upvote to the Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentUser` is not a plain object, it is an instance of the [User class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User). As you can see, it implements a `toJSON()` method which is automatically detected and used by `JSON.stringify` as the canonical way to transform the object into JSON.

If you want to merge custom properties onto a Firebase user, you could just add `toJSON()` first:

```
var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.toJSON();
```

this will translate the User object into a plain object which would then be able to have additional properties added and still serialize as expected. Note, however, that this obviously won't persist on the user either server-side or on `firebase.auth().currentUser`.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, @Michael Bleigh! You can't iagine the HOURS I eas searching fr this answer! On Angular if you (user$ | async), the "plain" object gets printed on the HTML. But everytime I was trying to manipulate it on the TS... errors were thrown! With `toJSON()` you onle get the "good" porperties - easy to manipulate and no errors! TX!