# Cannot read property 'uid' of null in firebase and angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, userid

Before, I was using storage to pass UID from login page to any page. Then I found, **firebase.auth().currentUser.uid** to get the user ID from anywhere. But, it gives me an error Cannot read property.  When I login, it works perfectly but then I refresh it throws that error. I have already check solution in from other posts but still couldn't understand. 
And everytime, I did

```
console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
```

it gives me value  but here it it throws an error.

```js
async ngOnInit() {
this.afStore.collection('Students').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).valueChanges().subscribe(data=>{
      this.firebaseData = data

    },error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  }
```

Comment: maybe duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883981/cant-get-currentuser-on-load

Comment: Yeah. its same problem. I am trying to figure out in angular.