# Firebase javascript auth user displaying null even though user is signed in

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I followed the Firebase docs for web development and I used the `user.updateProfile` method to add a display name to the user's profile. After signing in, I used `console.log(user)` and it worked but when I call `updateProfile()`, the value of `user` is null. Any solutions?

Here is the relevant code:

```
var button = document.getElementById("profile-button");
var username = document.getElementById("username-Box").value;

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

auth.onAuthStateChanged(user =>{
    console.log(user);
})


function updateProfile(){
    if (user != null){
        user.updateProfile({
        displayName : username
    }).then(user => {
        console.log("Updated Successfully");
        window.location.href="chatpage.html";
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log(err);
        window.alert(err);
    });
    }else if(user == null){
        console.log("No user signed in");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns null"? What returns null?  Please edit the question to be specific about what you're observing.

Comment: the firebase.auth().currentUser statement returns null

Comment: It returns null when there is no user signed in.  Your code should be prepared to handle that case.

Comment: No, my problem is that after using the "createUserWithEmailAndPassword" method, I made it redirect to this page, and now there is no current user signed in

Comment: It won't contain a value immediately.  You should to use the listener approaches in the answers below in order to find it when the user object is first available in the newly loaded page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883981/cant-get-currentuser-on-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for `onAuthStateChanged` to fire before assigning the `user` variable, otherwise the Auth object may be in an intermediate state.  This is [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users):

> By using an observer, you ensure that the Auth object isn't in an intermediate state—such as initialization—when you get the current user. When you use signInWithRedirect, the onAuthStateChanged observer waits until getRedirectResult resolves before triggering.
>
> You can also get the currently signed-in user by using the currentUser property. If a user isn't signed in, **currentUser is null**:

It's worth explicitly pointing out that the `user` variable you `console.log` in `onAuthStateChanged` is not the same `user` variable that's used in your `updateProfile` method.  While the user maybe "logged in" when `onAuthStateChanged` fires, they are likely not logged in when you set your outer `user` variable.  Therein lies your problem.

It's not clear from your code where `updateProfile` is called, but [Peter Haddad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546235/3977276) is likely the solution I would implement.  However, note that with the code snippet supplied in that answer you'll also need to change your `updateProfile` method to accept a `user` parameter.  Another approach would be to assign the `user` variable inside of `onAuthStateChanged`.

```
let user;

auth.onAuthStateChanged(u => user = u);
```

With that approach your `updateProfile` method should work as is.  Just keep in mind that you may have a race condition depending on when you call `updateProfile`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `console.log(user)` is returning the correct user, then inside the `authstatechanged` call the `updateProfile`:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user =>{
    console.log(user);
    updateProfile(user);
})
```

Comment: Pass the value in updateProfile(user) then function updateProfile(user){}

Answer (score 0):

Based on your snippet, I am assuming that `updateProfile()` is your `onClick`/`onSubmit` event handler for clicking your "update profile" button.

Because of this, your user is likely to have logged in by the time they press the button and therefore it is safe to use `firebase.auth().currentUser` in your event handler rather than maintain a `user` object in the global scope.

```js
var eleButton = document.getElementById("profile-button");
var eleUsername = document.getElementById("username-Box");

function updateProfile() {
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  if (!user) {
    alert('Please log in before clicking update profile!')
    return;
  }

  // get current value of '#username-Box'
  let username = eleUsername.value.trim();

  if (!username) {
    alert('Please enter a valid username!')
    return;
  }

  user.updateProfile({
    displayName : username
  }).then(user => {
    console.log("Updated Successfully");
    window.location.href="chatpage.html";
  }).catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
    window.alert(err);
  });
}
```

In your original code, you had the following:

```js
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; // <-- global-scope variable

auth.onAuthStateChanged(user =>{ // <-- function-scope variable
    console.log(user);
})
```

When `onAuthStateChanged` fires, it does log the value of `user`, but it sets and logs it's own version of `user`, not the `user` variable in the global-scope.

If you wanted to update the global-scope version, you need to rename the variable used in your `onAuthStateChanged` handler so that it doesn't shadow the `user` global-scope variable.

```js
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; // <-- global-scope variable

auth.onAuthStateChanged(_user =>{ // <-- function-scope variable
    user = _user;
    console.log(user);
})
```

Comment: Also note how I rewrote your `updateProfile()` function to 'fail-fast'. Rather than have `if (condition) { /* ...lots of code... */ } else { throw new Error() }`, it's better to do `if (!condition) { throw new Error() } /*... remainder of code ...*/`. This will make it easier to find what is actually causing an error by putting the failing condition and error right next to each other in your code while also reducing the amount of indentation your code has.